# iOS pathForResource has prompt error when json in a directory

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have put my json file (targetJson) in the json_container folder. but `NSBundle` cannot read with "inDirectory".

file location:

```
projectName_folder/projectName_folder/json_container/targetJson.json
```

swift (have tried):

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("targetJson", ofType: "json", inDirectory: "projectName_folder/projectName_folder/json_container")

let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("targetJson", ofType: "json", inDirectory: "projectName_folder/json_container")

let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("targetJson", ofType: "json", inDirectory: "json_container")
```

Thank you very much for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("targetJson", ofType: "json", inDirectory: nil)
```

No need to specify the folder there, unless you added that folder as reference. Just open your app package content, you can see the exact location of file in the app. If the folder is not added as a reference, the file will be in the root folder of the application package.